# Compiling for ToolsVersion 12 with Visual Studio 2015

Tags: msbuild, visual-studio-2015

I setup a new computer and installed VS2015. Compiling the project I am currently work on results in some invalid code (ILSpy creates uncompilable sources). It worked fine in VS2013 using ToolsVersion 12.

Log file tells me that ToolsVersion 12 is missing, so I installed this. However whatever I do or set, it ALWAYS compiles using ToolsVersion 14. I can manually call `MSBuild.exe` shipped with VS2013 (uses ToolsVersion 12) and code is correct. Doing the same with `MSBuild.exe` shipped with VS2015 (uses ToolsVersion 14) results in the INCORRECT code. So all I need is VS2015 to use ToolSet 12.

MSDN says:

"Starting in Visual Studio 2013, the MSBuild Toolset version is the same as the Visual Studio version number. MSBuild defaults to this Toolset within Visual Studio and on the command line, *regardless of the ToolSet version specified in project file*. This behavior can be overridden by using the /ToolsVersion flag. For more information, see Overriding ToolsVersion Settings."

Setting such using MSBuild manually works fine, but how do I set this in VS 2015 ?? NONE of the environment variables work, it always uses toolset 14 !

Comment: You will have to uninstall .NET 4.6 so that the Roslyn based compilers are removed. Otherwise, the C# compiler might continue to give you the same invalid assemblies. But generally speaking, ILSpy does not work well with Roslyn compiled assemblies. So your assemblies might be indeed valid, just ILSpy cannot understand them. You can check ILSpy bug list to learn more about that.

Comment: Sorry, your suggestion does not fix the problem ! The issue really is that VS uses MSBuild 14. As I mentioned before if I ran MSBuild from the 12 folder all is fine. I renamed the 14 folder and now VS does not load the projects, so its looking for the 14 folder. The solution is simple IF one would know how to change/set the $(MSBuildToolsVersion) variable. This is obviously set to 14 and the ToolsVersion attribute is not honored anymore (as Microsoft states without giving a working solution for a replacement). I renamed the 14 folder to 12 and that results in other crashes... ARGH !

Comment: I'm not sure why this has been downvoted.  The question still appears to be "How do I get VS2015 to build with an earlier ToolsVersion?"

Comment: VS2015 is *very* different from previous VS versions, Roslyn was integrated and that had a big impact on the IDE.  All of the editor features depend on Roslyn-generated metadata.  Earlier toolversions of course don't know beans about Roslyn.  If you need to do this only because ILSpy cannot keep up then just use another decompiler.  Reflector v9 has good C# v6 support.

Answer (score 3):

*I'm leaving this answer here in case it helps anyone else, however it hasn't helped the original poster, as according to @user1029883 it doesn't work when VS2015 is installed with the 12.0 Build Tools (see @alexandrul's comment below) instead of multiple versions of Visual Studio: sorry.*

---

Unfortunately, there doesn't seem to be a *straightforward* way to do this.  There is, however, a fiddly way:

- Set the environment variable `MSBUILDLEGACYDEFAULTTOOLSVERSION`
- Ensure the `ToolsVersion` attribute in the top-level `Project` element in all your project files is set to the desired `ToolsVersion`.

See  the [*Overriding ToolsVersion Settings* page on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383985.aspx)

Comment: I tried that before, it does not work.  Below my top project file and environment variable:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="12.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">




MSBUILDLEGACYDEFAULTTOOLSVERSION 1

Comment: Pardon my ignorance: how did you install toolsversion 12.0 without installing VS2013?

Comment: @GuyBoltonKing http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40760 "If you don't have Visual Studio installed on your computer, you can use Build Tools 2013 to build managed applications. The Visual Basic and C# compilers are also included in this download. (In earlier versions, these tools were included in the stand-alone .NET Framework.)"

Comment: That's exactly what I did, downloaded and installed the toolset. As I posted in my original message, using csc and msbuild out of the 12 toolset manually work fine. Still no working solution to have that called from vs 2015.

Comment: @GuyBoltonKing Its not "INSTEAD". I have VS2015 installed and manually installed tools version 12.  According to MSDN docs this should work but does not. Maybe it does if VS 2012 is installed in addition to VS2015.