# Jenkins or Windows is using same MSBUILD to compile projects regardless of multiple MSBUILD's defined

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, jenkins, msbuild, visual-studio-2015

On my Jenkins Slave I am trying to get Visual Studio 2012 and Visual Studio 2015 to peacefully coexist but don't understand why it isn't working.  Under my Jenkins Configuration I have TWO MSBuild installations defined as follows:

```
Name: .NET 4.0
Path to MSBuild: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe
Default parameters: /nologo /target:Build /consoleloggerparameters:PerformanceSummary;ShowCommandLine;ShowTimestamp

Name: .NET 4.6
Path to MSBuild: C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\MSBuild.exe
Default parameters: /p:VisualStudioVersion=15.0 /nologo /target:Build /consoleloggerparameters:PerformanceSummary;ShowCommandLine;ShowTimestamp
```

As you can see VS2015 Msbuild is now in a separate directory under C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\MSBuild.exe, the old one (VS2012) located at C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe.

In my Jenkins Job I have configured it to use the VS2015 MSBUILD (.NET 4.6) but when it builds it is using the VS2012 (.NET 4.0) MSBUILD.

So how do I call the VS2015 compiler from any of my jenkins jobs?  Is there some undocumented magic with msbuild to support 2 different sets of tools (they’re both installed on my build vm in different paths)?  Is this something that will have to be defined as a property in all project files?  Since the builds are calling msbuild, I can't run something like vcvars to set paths since there’s no persistence between windows ’spawn’ calls / jenkins build steps and since the jenkins slave is a service can’t just ‘restart’ with each build.  I've unsuccessfully tried to inject variables into the build via an external file as well.

Ideas from you out in the field?

Comment: Just some guesses, can you try for a test to 1. rename the MSBuild installations to something without special characters, just to be sure there isnt some oddity in string comparison for version selection. 2. delete the build step & save, then add it again "fresh" 3. Is there anything odd in jenkins logfile?

Comment: @DominikGebhart Let me backtrack a little.  In the Jenkins Console Output I see that it selected the correct MSBUILD (in this case 4.6) but later on when it is using other libraries like CL.EXE, it is using the older installation instead of that which came with 4.6.  For example, CL.EXE from **C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0 is being used instead of CL.EXE** from **C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0**

Comment: @DominikGebhart For example, in Jenkins Console Output I can see that it is using the right MSBUILD:

**Path To MSBuild.exe: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\14.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe
Executing the command cmd.exe /C " C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\14.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe**

Comment: @DominikGebhart But later on in the log it is using CL.exe from Visual Studio 11.

**13:30:11.120     3>ClCompile:
                     C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\bin\CL.exe**

Comment: Is maybe the wrong toolchain/folders referenced in your VS project file?

Comment: Also, does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34065614/is-there-a-simple-way-to-make-visual-studio-2015-use-a-specific-toolsversion) thread help you further?

Comment: @DominikGebhart Thanks for the link to that thread.  It sounds just like my problem.  I will try it on Monday and report back.